# Does moving away from under a flying opponent provoke an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, flight

If a rogue with flying ends their turn 5 ft above someone, does that mean the target cannot move without provoking an attack of opportunity (and thus, a potential Sneak Attack)?

The two parties are already engaged in combat, so all pursuant rules apply. Also, I realize they can spend their action to Disengage, but the question still holds.

Comment: [A possibly related question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72665/does-moving-behind-full-cover-count-as-leaving-the-opponents-reach-for-purpos/72666#72666)

Answer (score 11):

**Yes**

I'm not sure why there is any doubt about this:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile
>   creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

If the putative rogue has a reach of 5 feet or more, a reaction available and the target is visible then if the target leave's the rogue's reach using their own movement then they rogue can launch an Attack of Opportunity.

Comment: The only doubt was due to the not knowing if flight affected the results in any way. Thank you.

Comment: What is it in the rules on flying that led you to this doubt?

Comment: Unfamiliarity with the rules can lead one to verify that they are not making an assumption based on insufficient knowledge. I.e. You don't know what you don't know. I don't think the "I'm not sure why there is any doubt about this" adds anything useful to the answer.