# Opportunity Attacks and move-through-walls

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, wall

There are a few ways to achieve "this person walks through the wall" in 5e; and I suspect the exact mechanics aren't too important for the question.

Suppose I have an enemy backed into a corner, in combat, and they respond by walking through the wall ... do I get an OA?

In particular, if I further have Sentinel, am I able to prevent them from walking through the wall in question?

Is the answer any different if the movement is "sink through the floor"?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Yup; agree that's a match.

Comment: @Someone_Evil: our DM ruled (the opponents were lava children in a heap of metal dungeon, but effectively the same situation) that we could not hit them with opportunity attacks when they retreated into the walls, as they only left our space by entering the solid metal adjacent to it, so by the time they had left, they were already fully behind cover. I think this situation is different from the dupe target in this regard (where there is no such obstacle). We had to ready actions to try and hit them as they emerged on their turn, which cost us our ability to use full attack actions.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin A given specific situation that is (believed) different to the ghost example would be a unique question and should be asked as such, though I'd hasted to point out that a DM can rule something other than RAW (or that an upvoted answer finds to be true).

Comment: I initially posted agreeing with @Someone_Evil, but on further reading, it's curiously more the 2nd portions of the *answer* that answer my question, rather than the question being a dupe, per se.

Comment: @Someone_Evil if a question gets an answer that also covers a close-but-not-identical topic, then is that question a dupe of the 2nd topic?

Comment: I might argue that this is a closer dupe: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72665/does-moving-behind-full-cover-count-as-leaving-the-opponents-reach-for-purpos

Comment: I think you're right, for some reason I thought the ghost question was about it moving out through a wall not through a creature. I've changed the dupe-mark over. As a general note, we close question as dupes of other questions, not their answers (though answers can often be a good indicator of what the question is actually about).

Comment: If you are going to ask about 5th edition, it is best to use 5th edition terms where they differ from other editions.  Opportunity Attack is the term for this edition.  It's in Chapter 9.